# How to get the default minimum size of a Swing component?

Tags: java, swing, size, awt, jbutton

There is a way to get the "default minimum size"/"content size" of a Component?

I mean, for example: if you create a new empty `JButton`, it is created with a minimum size of `java.awt.Dimension[width=34,height=10]`, but, if you create a new button with some text, like "XXXXX", it is create with a minimum size of `[width=74,height=26]`. That is what I call the "default minimum size" or the "content size".

My problem is: if I need to change the `minimumSize` of a button (for example, to achieve some behaviour of a `GridBagLayout`), but then I need the old default minimum size back, there is a way to get it?

You would say, easy, save it into a variable... but, if I save it, and then I change the content of the component (thus, its "content size")?
Because, if you haven't changed the button `minimumSize`, and you change its text, its `minimumSize` changes accordingly; but, if you change its minimumSize, and then you change its text, its minimumSize remain the "manually changed", and it is not updated to the new content (the text changed).

Comment: You shouldn’t have to change the minimumSize just to achieve desired behavior in GridBagLayout.  What GridBagLayout behavior do you desire?

Comment: You use the `getPreferredSize()` method. However, you should not be trying to play with any size manually. The preferred size is automatically recalculated whenever you change a property (text, font, border etc.) of the component. The layout manager with then automatically adjust the layout of the components on the panel.

Comment: @VGR the weightx and weighty affect the space of the cell that exceeds the component minimumSize (or the preferredSize, the minimum of both), so if you assing the same weightx to a two components with different minimum size, you dont achieve a 50%-50% distribution on x axis. I want to assign the same minimumSize (in fact, the minimum minimumSize of all components) to all components in x axis to achieve a weightx proportional size

Comment: You’re correct that GridBagLayout cannot make its children have proportional sizes.  I would use [SpringLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SpringLayout.html) for that.  Then you won’t have to fiddle with minimum sizes directly.

Comment: `space of the cell that exceeds the component minimumSize ` - it is the preferred size that is used. In the case of a JButton the minimum and preferred happen to be the same, but this may not be true of all components.  `if you assing the same weightx to a two components with different minimum size, you dont achieve a 50%-50% distribution on x axis` - you could use the [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/) which was designed specifically for this purpose.